# Return one ID only from array of object (REST API)

Tags: angular, api, rest

Trying to return one ID only , when click the edit bank form it will initiate the get bank list API , from that particular API I want to return the bank ID inside it to use it on another API call. can someone point what's wrong with my code and why ?

```
id: any;

getBankId(){
    // Get ID
    this.service.GetBankList(this.uid)
    .subscribe((banko:bankListDTO) => {
    return this.id = banko.id,
    console.log('should be bank ID', this.id);
    })
  }
```

I got this error in console
[image: I got this error, it detects it as undefined]

[image: the array of object]

Thank you for your kindness

Updated code

HTML

```
<div class="animated fadeIn">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
          <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
              Bank list

              <div class="card-header-actions">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" (click)="openModal(template , this.isAddMode=true)">Add New Bank</button>
            </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <form [formGroup]="bankForm" novalidate>
                  <table datatable #dtable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Bank name</th>
                          <th>Holder name</th>
                          <th>Account number</th>
                          <th>isdefault</th>
                          <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let item of this.bankList">
                          <td>{{item.bankName}}</td>
                          <td>{{item.holderName}}</td>
                          <td>{{item.bankAccountNumber}}</td>
                          <td>{{item.isDefault}}</td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
                              <button id="button-basic" dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
                                      aria-controls="dropdown-basic">
                                Action <span class="caret"></span>
                              </button>
                              <ul id="dropdown-basic" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu"
                                  role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-basic">
                                <li role="menuitem"><button (click)="openModal(template , this.isAddMode=false)" class="dropdown-item" >Edit</button></li>
                                <li role="menuitem"><button class="dropdown-item" (click)="this.removeBank(item.id)" >Remove</button></li>
                              </ul>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                </form>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- "this.loadDetail(item.id)" -->

<!-- Add/Edit form Modal -->
<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left" *ngIf="isAddMode">Add Bank</h4>
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left" *ngIf="!isAddMode">Edit Bank</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form [formGroup]="this.bankForm" >
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputName" class="label">Bank Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" fullWidth id="inputName"
                      formControlName="bankName" placeholder="bank Name">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputName" class="label">Holder Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" fullWidth id="inputName"
                    formControlName="holderName" placeholder="holder Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputName" class="label">Bank Account Number</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" fullWidth id="inputName"
                  formControlName="bankAccountNumber" placeholder="bank account number">
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="isDefault">Default bank account</mat-slide-toggle>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="modalRef.hide()">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" (click)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="!bankForm.valid">Save</button>
      <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="this.saveBank()" [disabled]="!this.bankForm.valid">Save changes</button> -->
  </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

component.ts

```
// Stack Overflow
  async getBankId(){
    // Get ID
    await this.service.GetBanko(this.uid)
    .then((banko:any) => {
    this.id =+ banko.filter((x,index) => index ==0).map( x => x.id).join();
    console.log('should be bank ID', this.id);
    })
  }
```

service.ts

```
public async GetBanko(uid) {
      return await this.httpClient.get(environment.host + 'therapist-bank/bank/' + uid).toPromise();
    }
```

[image: console]

Comment: remove return keyword and console the banko (console.log(banko)) to see the object>

Then share the result of console. I am thinking it's may be array

Comment: @PalashKantiBachar I already update my question yup, you are right it's an array

Comment: you will need to loop banko to get all ids

Comment: @PalashKantiBachar , I only want the one particular ID when clicking the edit button for one bank detail

Comment: so you clicked on one bank edit button but you are getting list of all banks. and now you need to get id of that specific bank you clicked on to get its details.

Comment: @PalashKantiBachar yes sir , that's corrrect

Comment: this is not a good way. its too much work. develop a new  backend api to get the data associated with that particular edit button so you do not have to loop through all the list each time edit is clicked just to get the required data.

Comment: @AliTahir, I'm a front-end developer . yup, that's a better way , but the back-end developer told me to figure it out myself. so here I am hahaha

Comment: hahaha. you seem nice, If its a professional project I would've generated a ticket for a new service requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can use async-await to get the data from the server, when your request will be completed and id will be available then it will work for the next call.

for [More](https://balramchavan.medium.com/using-async-await-feature-in-angular-587dd56fdc77)

```
id: any;
async getBankId(){
    // Get ID
   await this.service.GetBankList(this.uid)
    .then((banko:bankListDTO) => {
     this.id =+banko.filter((x,index)=> index==0).map(x=> x.id).join(); 
    console.log('should be bank ID', this.id);
    })
  }


/// service method will be added async-await

public async GetBankList(){
    return await this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion , got a status "404" , statusText "not found" . I haven't develop a back-end API .. is the error possible due to the API cannot handle async-await method ? sorry if the question sounds dumb

Comment: Could you share your code? So that I can help you.

Comment: sure , I just updated the code in my question

Comment: Could you change the api url to test ur app is working or not. Url : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Comment: And console the banko object. To confirm that working this code.

Comment: i already console banko , it still displays that error

Comment: Sure that your API has problem so update the api and try again.